# Visualization of data coming from a JOIN query SqLite in Android

Tags: join, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

for the first time I stumbled upon the concept of INNER JOIN with SqlLite while programming for Android. 
I managed to get something back but the problem now is that I want to display the data in a List and I cannot display the information as I supposed to.

Here is the query that retrieve the data

```
cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT matchesbet._id, hometeam, awayteam, gamble " +
                    "FROM matchesbet INNER JOIN gambles ON matchesbet.idmatch = gambles.idmatch " +
                    "WHERE matchesbet.idbet = ? GROUP BY matchesbet.idmatch ORDER BY matchesbet._id DESC", selectionArgs);
```

The data are used in a class which extends CursorAdapter in the bindView method

```
    TextView tvGamble = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gamble_text_view);

    // Extract properties from cursor
    int gamble = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("gamble"));

    tvGamble.setText(String.valueOf(gamble));
```

Now in the DB I save multiple "gamble" for each match but the only thing that I can display is 1 gamble.

Db tables structure and sample data

```
MATCHESBET
    +-----+-------+---------+----------+-----------+--+
    | id  | idbet | idmatch | hometeam | awayteam  |  |
    +-----+-------+---------+----------+-----------+--+
    | 349 |  3000 |      27 | TeamA    | TeamZ     |  |
    | 350 |  2456 |      39 | TeamC    | TeamG     |  |
    | 351 |  2818 |      20 | TeamW    | TeamB     |  |
    +-----+-------+---------+----------+-----------+--+

    GAMBLES
    +-----+---------+--------+-------+
    | _id | idmatch | gamble | idbet |
    +-----+---------+--------+-------+
    | 349 |      27 | WIN    |  3000 |
    | 350 |      27 | LOST   |  3000 |
    | 351 |      27 | DRAW   |  3000 |
    | 489 |    1345 | WIN    |  1981 |
    +-----+---------+--------+-------+
```

Besed on the above data considering that I filter the Bet with ID = 3000 I would like to have a listItem with TeamA vs TeamZ (ID = 27) and in the same Row the string WIN, LOST, DRAW. Then iterate again through all the matches that have as IDBET = 3000

I'm not sure how to get out of this situation
Hope someone can help
Cheers

Comment: if you add the line (after retrieving the cursor) `Log.d("CRSCOUNT","Number of rows in Cursor is " + cursor.getCount());`, run and the count is not greater than 1 then it is likely that the WHERE condition is the cause. If so then perhaps try using `cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT matchesbet._id, hometeam, awayteam, gamble " +
                    "FROM matchesbet INNER JOIN gambles ON matchesbet.idmatch = gambles.idmatch " +
                    "GROUP BY matchesbet.idmatch ORDER BY matchesbet._id DESC", null);`

Comment: The only thing that I noticed is that by removing the GROUP BY I will retrieve the 3 elements coming from the gambles table. But once I displayed I have 3 elements in the list. What I would like to achieve is one List element and in the textView contained in the ListView the 3 elements of the gambles table.

Comment: I forgot the WHERE condition is mandatory to extract the proper records from the matchesbet table.

Comment: Can you add the layout of the two tables with some sample data.

Comment: I hope is a bit more clear now.

Comment: Hi. It's not clear what you want to do. Please clarify via post edits not comments. Please read & act on [mcvc]. That inludes showing DDL & for this input the output from your current query & desired output. Looks like you might want to select group_concat(gamble). Please google my comments re googling many phrasings of your question. If you had made a clear statement about having a column whose value is the concatenation of strings ... a group ... etc ... (or whatever your question is) then you would llikely hit a faq about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is as simple as :-

```
SELECT matchesbet._id, hometeam, awayteam, group_concat(gamble) AS gamble 
FROM matchesbet JOIN gambles ON  gambles.idmatch = matchesbet.idmatch
WHERE matchesbet.idbet = 3000 
GROUP BY matchesbet.idmatch 
ORDER BY matchesbet._id DESC;
```

i.e. Keeping the `GROUP` but instead of selecting column `gamble` selecting a column that is **`group_concat(gamble) AS gamble`**.

By default the values are separated by a **`,`**. However you can specify another separator via a 2nd parameter e.g. `group_concat(gamble,' - ')` would
give :-

[image]

You may find this link helpful [Aggregate Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat)